# is it possible to unzip a .apk file(or generally any zipped file) into memory instead of writing it to fs

Tags: android, python, unzip

I am doing research with mobile apps and need to analyze their code after unzipping the .apk file. However, the process of unzipping naturally involves lots of IO, which doesn't make it scalable, I am thinking if it's possible to hold the unzipped data in memory, with several variables representing it, thus saving the trouble of writing to FS. I am loaded with thousands of apps to analyze, so being able to do something like this would significantly speed up my process.  Is there anyone who can suggest a way out for me. I am using python. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: there seem to be quite a few posts on stack overflow regarding this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908877/extracting-a-zipfile-to-memory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710867/python-downloading-and-unzipping-a-zip-file-without-writing-to-disk

Comment: Sounds like you want unzip code that doesn't save the data at all (as opposed to saving it in a memory buffer).  Maybe just take https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/include/utils/ZipFileRO.h and tweak it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope you are using Linux:

```
$ cd /dev/shm
$ unzip /path/to/my.apk
```

that's it. Unzipped APK in memory.

Comment: that seems to be a quick way to work around this issue. Thanks! I did a quick google and find that, /dev/shm, /tmp, /var/tmp /run can all serve as temporary memory storage. But I am not quite sure how they differ from each other, and in my case which one should I use. specifically /tmp and /var/tmp is mounted on filesystem /dev/sda6, /run is on tmpfs, and /dev/shm is on none. what's the different among them, and how are they related to memory when they are literally mounted on a device in the case of /tmp and /var/tmp

Comment: Check the filesystem type, if `tmpfs` it is in memory

Comment: how about /tmp and /var/tmp, on my computer it's /dev/sda6

Comment: df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6      191425164 50784288 130910368  28% /
xushunyi@xushunyi-Lenovo-G450:/dev$ df /var/tmp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the python [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) module lets you read files into memory. It reads file-like objects so the zipfile itself could be in memory also, if you find that useful.

Answer (score 0):

A late entry...but all I had to do was rename the file to a `.ZIP` extension.