# Extract zip to memory, parse contents

Tags: python, zip, stringio

I want to read the contents of a zip file into memory rather than extracting them to disc, find a particular file in the archive, open the file and extract a line from it.

Can a StringIO instance be opened and parsed? Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
zfile = ZipFile('name.zip', 'r')

    for name in zfile.namelist():
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, '*_readme.xml'):
            name = StringIO.StringIO()
            print name # prints StringIO instances
            open(name, 'r')  # IO Error: No such file or directory...
```

I found a few similar posts, but none that seem to address this issue: [Extracting a zipfile to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908877/extracting-a-zipfile-to-memory)

Comment: Why would you like to open a file, that doesn't exists? An instance of `StringIO` already acts like an opened file.

Comment: @luk32 I agree, can a StringIO instance be opened and parsed?

Comment: It cannot be opened, because it does not make sense. It can be parsed, but I don't think you need it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that contributed solutions. This is what ended up working for me:

```
zfile = ZipFile('name.zip', 'r')

        for name in zfile.namelist():
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, '*_readme.xml'):
                zopen = zfile.open(name)
                for line in zopen:
                    if re.match('(.*)<foo>(.*)</foo>(.*)', line):
                        print line
```

Answer (score 4):

IMO just using `read` is enough:

```
zfile = ZipFile('name.zip', 'r')
files = []
for name in zfile.namelist():
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, '*_readme.xml'):
    files.append(zfile.read(name))
```

This will make a list with contents of files that match the pattern.

Test:
You can then parse contents afterwards by iterating through the list:

```
for file in files:
  print(file[0:min(35,len(file))].decode()) # "parsing"
```

Or better use a functor:

```
import zipfile as zip
import os
import fnmatch

zip_name = os.sys.argv[1]
zfile = zip.ZipFile(zip_name, 'r')

def parse(contents, member_name = ""):
  if len(member_name) > 0:
    print( "Parsed `{}`:".format(member_name) )  
  print(contents[0:min(35, len(contents))].decode()) # "parsing"

for name in zfile.namelist():
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, '*.cpp'):
    parse(zfile.read(name), name)
```

This way there is no data kept in memory for no reason and memory foot print is smaller. It might be important if the files are big.

Answer (score 3):

Don't overthink it. It Just Works:

```
import zipfile

# 1) I want to read the contents of a zip file ...
with zipfile.ZipFile('A-Zip-File.zip') as zipper:
  # 2) ... find a particular file in the archive, open the file ...
  with zipper.open('A-Particular-File.txt') as fp:
    # 3) ... and extract a line from it.
    first_line = fp.readline()

print first_line
```

Answer (score 1):

The question you link shows you that you need to read the file. Depending on your use case that may already be enough. In your code you replace the loop variable holding a filename with an empty string buffer. Try something like this:

```
zfile = ZipFile('name.zip', 'r')

for name in zfile.namelist():
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, '*_readme.xml'):
        ex_file = zfile.open(name) # this is a file like object
        content = ex_file.read() # now file-contents are a single string
```

If you really want a buffer that you can manipulate, then simply instantiate it with the contents:

```
buf = StringIO(zfile.open(name).read())
```

You may also want to look at `BytesIO` and note that there are differences between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Just note, that `content` will have last matching file. It will get overwritten for each hit. I think the `namelist()` can return names in an arbitrary order. I am not sure.

Comment: I would expect the content to be used in the loop but you are correct, of course.

Comment: Oh, sure, of course I should have added "after the loop", to be precise and correct.