# How to unzip files from an online source and then use them without saving on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, zip

```
url = 'https://ihmecovid19storage.blob.core.windows.net/latest/ihme-covid19.zip'

from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

resp = urlopen(url)
zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(resp.read()))
print(zipfile.namelist()[-2])
print(zipfile.namelist()[-1])

a = zipfile.open(zipfile.namelist()[-2])
df2  = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df2)
```

I'm stuck on reading part. When I convert the "a" to a dataframe, it gives me just one column. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909949/11728401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the CSV with `df2  = pd.read_csv(a)`